# Update multiple workstations descriptions via powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am working in Powershell to **update multiple workstation descriptions from a `.csv` file.** The `.csv` file has contents looks something like this:

```
Workstation,Description
workstation1,description1
workstation2,description2
```

I want my script to look at the first column to get the workstation name then use `Win32_OperatingSystem` class and update the description of the computer with the information in the second column. Here is my code:

```
$myarray = Import-CSV -Path "workstations.csv" -Delimiter ',' 
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -cn $myarray.Workstation
$wmi.Description = $myarray.Description
$wmi.Put()
```

The problem I am running into is that when Powershell gets to the `$wmi.Description = $myarray.Description` line it is telling me *"The property 'Description' cannot be found on this object."*

Not sure where to go from here. I know the description is getting saved to the variable because I can output the contents of the variable with `write-host`.... Any tips or suggestions? It seems like a simple script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is because the line below is retrieving an array of objects from the computers specified.

```
$wmi = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -cn $myarray.Workstation
```

you can try using foreach in $myarray and the code should work fine

Full code:

```
$myarray = Import-CSV -Path "workstations.csv" -Delimiter ',' 
foreach ($x in $myarray)
{ 

$wmi = Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -cn $x.workstation
$wmi.Description = $x.description
$wmi.Put()
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you mean by "in" `$myarray.workstation`? If I edit the above to contain the foreach I still get the same error.

Comment: @Ozar I have updated the answer can you check with full code?

Comment: You, sir, rock. Thank you so much.